# R language assign character value as data set name

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I need to process hundreds of data frames through the same set of code. For illustrative purposes, I create 3 data frames:

```
ds.1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15,
                          0.2, 1, 0.15, 0.15,
                          0.2, .15, 1, 0.15,
                          0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
ds.2 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
                          0.2, 1, 0.25, 0.25,
                          0.2, .25, 1, 0.25,
                          0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
ds.3 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50,
                          0.2, 1, 0.50, 0.50,
                          0.2, .50, 1, 0.50,
                          0.2, 0.50, 0.50, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
```

I then assign the data frame names to a vector.

```
ds.vector <- c("ds.1", "ds.2", "ds.3")  #create a vector of data set names
```

I count the number of data frames in the vector

```
ds.in.vector <- length(ds.vector) #count the number of elements in vector
```

I loop through the vector, and seek to assign the data frame name to a data frame called ds.  I would then run the code on ds.

```
for (i in 1:ds.in.vector)
   {
     ds <- ds.vector[i] #copy each of the data sets into ds
     #There would be a bunch of code here. For this example, 
     # I will just try to print
     print(ds)
   }
```

The line:
    ds <- ds.vector[i]
does not copy the data frame whose name is in the vector, into ds. Rather, it copies the character string of the vector into ds.

Comment: Are you sure you need assign here? There is probably a better way to do this, for instance by using lapply, combining all your dataframes (with a grouping variable) to a larger dataframe/data.table etc. How are you generating all these dataframes?

Comment: Heroka,  Thank you for your response.  The data frames are correlation matricies that contain the point estimates from a meta-analysis.

Comment: I think you just need `mget(ls(pattern = "ds"))` in order to save them all into a list and then either combine them into a single data set or use `lapply` (as mentioned already).

Comment: How on earth are you getting hundreds of dataframes assigned in your global environment?

Answer (score 3):

These data.frames belong into a list. You should assign them into one when you create them. Having hundreds of data.frames in your global environment is just crazy and really not practical.

```
ds.list <- list(

ds.1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15,
                              0.2, 1, 0.15, 0.15,
                              0.2, .15, 1, 0.15,
                              0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4)),
ds.2 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
                              0.2, 1, 0.25, 0.25,
                              0.2, .25, 1, 0.25,
                              0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4)),
ds.3 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 0.50, 0.50, 0.50,
                              0.2, 1, 0.50, 0.50,
                              0.2, .50, 1, 0.50,
                              0.2, 0.50, 0.50, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
)

ds.vector <- c("ds.1", "ds.2", "ds.3") 


for (i in seq_along(ds.vector)) {
  ds <- ds.list[ds.vector[i]] #copy each of the data sets into ds
  #There would be a bunch of code here. For this example, 
  # I will just try to print
  print(ds)
}
```

Of course, if they all have the same structure, you can combine them into one data structure:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(ds.list, idcol=TRUE)
DT[, print(.SD), by = .id]
```

Comment: I appreciate the responses. Do the concerns about hundreds of data sets in the global environment represent concerns about memory demands?  I offer two thoughts. 1) the data data frame are small. the largest would likely be 10 columns and 10 rows. 2) If R crashes or becomes uncooperative due to too many data frames, I can save the results to a file, clear the environment, and run the next set of data sets.   Does this make sense?  Have you figured out that I have never tried something like this before?

Comment: This yields null results. This would occur if the data sets already exist:   ds.list <- list(ds.1, ds.2, ds.3)
ds.list

ds.vector <- c("ds.1", "ds.2", "ds.3")  #create a vector of data set names


for (i in seq_along(ds.vector))
  {
    ds <- ds.list[ds.vector[i]] #copy each of the data sets into ds
    #There would be a bunch of code here. For this example, 
    # I will just try to print
    print(ds)
}

Comment: There is simply no reason to have them in a global environment. R doesn't care, but you should care. It's much easier to work with a list than the hassle of `assign`/`get` in conjunction with loops that you'll need with your approach. On your PC, do you put every file on your desktop or do you put them in folders?

Comment: Regarding your second comment: Your list doesn't have names if you create it that way. Use `mget(ls(pattern = "ds"))` as suggested by @David Arenburg to create it.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it (although not very efficient) is the following:

```
ds.cumulated <- get(ds.vector[1])
for (i in 2:ds.in.vector)
{
 ds.i <- get(ds.vector[i])
 ds.cumulated <- rbind(ds.cumulated, ds.i)
}
```